# Excel Resizing axis label area

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How do I resize the axis label area and make the long labels wrap?

[image: Chart]

The textbox formatting options are grayed out.

[image]

Comment: After selecting the chart, try selecting the area in question.

Comment: I ended removing the axis label to put the category name in the data label instead.

Comment: does inserting Alt+Enter in the source text box help?